# enable flash into a webview android app

Tags: java, android, flash, webview, youtube

I'm writing a music application and I want to integrate YouTube. I have done that but the videos can't be played so I want to enable flash on a `WebView` so I can  watch videos from YouTube on my own app.

**youtube.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**youtube.java:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Youtube extends Activity {

    public  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube);

        WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    }
}
```

**CustomWebViewClient.java:**

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }       
}
```

Something is not working with the `WebView` because the YouTube video does not play. Does anyone know whats wrong when I try and play YouTube with `WebView`?

Answer (score 1):

To make Flash Player work in a WebView you need to enable hardware acceleration in your androidmanifest.xml.

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

You can also individually enable it for your WebView by using

```
mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```